# How to open music picker?

Tags: android, gallery

In my application, I want to make a picker that offers the user the choice to pick a music. I want to use the native android picker. I used the following code to open the native android music picker:

```
final Intent intent2 = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK);
intent2.setType("audio/*");
startActivityForResult(intent2, 1);
```

But when I execute it, I get an ActivityNotFoundException and this error message:

"Your phone has no music gallery that can be used to select a file. Please try sending a different type of files"

Am I doing something wrong there ?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

This worked well for me:

```
public static final int REQ_PICK_AUDIO = 10001;
//------   
Intent audio_picker_intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK,
android.provider.MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
activity.startActivityForResult(audio_picker_intent, REQ_PICK_AUDIO);
```

The more general intent with Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT can present the user with a number of options for activities to pick an audio file (Astro file manager, etc.).  However, the user could select any file, not necessarily an audio file.  I wanted one that simply allowed the user to select an audio file from their media.  This did the trick.

Comment: Excellent, please give example for the file storing

Comment: see complete example here: http://sudhanshuvinodgupta.blogspot.co.il/2012/07/using-intentactionpick.html

Comment: `Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT` is indeed a nice picker... it even lets me open a file on my OneDrive. In Comparison, the `ACTION_PICK` of `Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI` is more concise... **question:** with ACTION_PICK method, how is it possible to pre-select the currently selected item ? (It shows the picker with nothing already selected)

Comment: @Craig This doesn't show downloaded music in some devices

Answer (score 8):

If you take a look at the [AndroidManifest.xml](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/packages/apps/Music/+/jb-release/AndroidManifest.xml) file for the latest core Music app, it may shed some light on the options that you have.  For example:

```
<activity android:name="com.android.music.MusicPicker"
        android:label="@string/music_picker_title" android:exported="true" >
    <!-- First way to invoke us: someone asks to get content of
         any of the audio types we support. -->
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.GET_CONTENT" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.OPENABLE" />
        <data android:mimeType="audio/*"/>
        <data android:mimeType="application/ogg"/>
        <data android:mimeType="application/x-ogg"/>
    </intent-filter>
    <!-- Second way to invoke us: someone asks to pick an item from
         some media Uri. -->
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.PICK" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.OPENABLE" />
        <data android:mimeType="vnd.android.cursor.dir/audio"/>
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

So based on this, you might first try

```
final Intent intent2 = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
intent2.setType("audio/*");
startActivityForResult(intent2, 1);
```

and see if it fits your needs.  You may also look at adding the category flags noted in the above example to help narrow down the results (e.g. `OPENABLE` should filter to only content that can be opened as a stream.

Answer (score 0):

Something along the lines of this may work

```
// some Intent that points to whatever you like to play
Intent play = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
play.setData(Uri.fromFile(new File("/path/to/file")));
// create chooser for that intent
try {
    Intent i = Intent.createChooser(play, "Play Music");
    c.startActivity(i);
} catch(ActivityNotFoundException ex) {
    // if no app handles it, do nothing
}
```