# LibGDX access to audio file in device's music library

Tags: libgdx

Is it possible with LibGDX to access the music picker interface to be able to play a song in the user's music library (a song that is already on the device and not bundled with the app)?

[image]

E.g. can the above interface be called through LibGDX and the chosen file returned to the LibGDX audio object?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is two solution:

1- explain in @m.antkowicz answer :
you can write your music chooser with libgdx ,you can get list of all music file in SD card and... .

2- if you wanna call default android music picker:
you most have interface in core project like this:

```
  interface MusicPicker{
      //@return selected path
      public String showPicker();
  }
```

and implement it in android project , in android project you can call audio picker and get file path @see [How to open music picker?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11938579/how-to-open-music-picker)

I hope be useful.

Comment: Yeah, I think only #2 works on iOS. I was hoping LibGDX had a way of accessing the default media pickers without having to write the native platform code, but I guess not. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

LibGDX support various types of [file handling](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/File-handling) - one of them is **External** and it allows you to read the files that are for example on SD card. Although I'm not sure what you mean by

> can the above interface be called through LibGDX

the answer is - **yes you can choose the file from the list** if you know where it is placed. Assuming that the *.mp3* file is in SD root location the example code would be:

```
    Music music = Gdx.audio.newMusic(Gdx.files.external("music.mp3"));
```

You should be also able to list file list by using:

```
    FileHandle directory = Gdx.files.external(""); //external root directory!
    for(FileHandle file : directory.list())
        System.out.println(file.name());
```

Of course you can also use your music directory like `Gdx.files.external("music/all/")`.

Notice that your app will need permissions to read from external storage! Read more about [Permissions](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Starter-classes-%26-configuration#permissions) here.

Comment: Thanks, unfortunately this would be without knowing where on the device the music would be stored. Worse, even if that were known, iOS doesn't actually store music files anywhere accessible and only lets you access them through their MediaPicker interface (the one in the screenshot)