# Sound picker through startActivityForResult from internal storage

Tags: java, android, xamarin, xamarin.android

I found similar questions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11938579/how-to-open-music-picker) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17042308/select-a-music-file-to-play-with-mediaplayer). For some reason, all the options I found worked only with `EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI`.

I used based on its approach and it works for me if I use `EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI`. But if I need to get the sounds from `INTERNAL_CONTENT_URI` I can't make choice in related application, which has opened by `startActivityForResult`. The app works like readonly.

Is there any way to make choice from `INTERNAL_CONTENT_URI`?
May be, I need some permissions?

My code adapted for Xamarin:

```
        const int REQ_PICK_AUDIO = 1;          
        Intent audio_picker_intent = new Intent(
            Intent.ActionPick, 
            Android.Provider.MediaStore.Audio.Media.InternalContentUri); // with ExternalContentUri it works
        XxmsApp.Droid.MainActivity.Instance.StartActivityForResult(audio_picker_intent, REQ_PICK_AUDIO);
```

Comment: @LeoZhu-MSFT, yes. You're right, it works. Thanks! But I find its no user-friendly, because the such behavior is not obvious for some users

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could get the content uri of the sounds which in the internal storage by `INTERNAL_CONTENT_URI`.

The codes above should work fine.You could get the sounds uri in the `OnActivityResult` method.

In your `MainActivity` over write the method :

```
protected override void OnActivityResult(int requestCode, Result resultCode, Intent data)
    {
        base.OnActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if (requestCode == 1)
        {
            var path = data.Data;  // you could get the sound uri.(e.g: content://media/external/audio/media/113)
        }
    }
```

**PS**:

I test on Android 10.0 emulator,when the `Intent.ActionPick` open the list,it doesn't seem to work when I select the sound, but when I click `OK`, it actually returns the `Uri` of the sound.

Like below:

[image]